# Replace with empty string replaces newChar around all the characters in original string

Tags: java, string, replace

I was just working on one of my java code in which I am using Java String.replace method. So while testing the replace method as in one situation I am planning to put junk value of `String.replace("","");`

so on Testing I came to a condition of replacing blank value with some other value i.e `String.replace("","p")` which replaced `"p"` everywhere around all the characters of the original String

Example:

```
String strSample = "val";
strSample = strSample.replace("","p");
System.out.println(strSample);
```

Output:

```
pvpaplp
```

Can anyone please explain why it works like this?

Comment: Which part is troubling you - the fact that it replaces the "in between"? Or the fact that it replaces more than one?

Comment: This is because `replace` uses a regular expressions and the regular expression `""` matches `val` at 4 places: before each letter and after the last.

Comment: `replace` doesn't use regex, `replaceAll` does.

Comment: @ForguesR It does, `replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)` uses `replaceAll` internally.

Comment: @ForguesR the current implementation "cheats". It uses the search pattern as a regular expression pattern, but with the `Pattern.LITERAL` flag.

Comment: @ForguesR replace doesn't use regex *syntax*, but it uses regex *engine*. It simply automatically adds escaping mechanisms to all regex metacharacters.

Comment: @tunaki Didn't look at the implementation.  Obviously in this case using regex yields to something weird.  This behavior seems contrary to many other language with a similar function.

Comment: @Tunaki - Thanks for the correct reply, and the type of detail I was looking for. 
Still I am not sure why regex pattern "" matches with all the places between and around all characters.

Also could you please post your comment as an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 5):

`replace` looks for each place that you have a String which starts with the replaced string. e.g. if you replace "a" in "banana" it finds "a" 3 times.

However, for empty string it finds it everywhere including before and after the last letter.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the definition from Java docs for the overloaded `replace` method of your case.

> String java.lang.String.replace(CharSequence **target**, CharSequence
>   **replacement**)
>
> Replaces each substring of this string that matches the literal target
>   sequence with the specified literal replacement sequence. The
>   replacement proceeds from the beginning of the string to the end, for
>   example, replacing "aa" with "b" in the string "aaa" will result in
>   "ba" rather than "ab".
>
> Parameters:
>   **target** The sequence of char values to be replaced
>   **replacement** The replacement sequence of char values

Now, since you are defining `target` value as `""` i.e. empty, so it will pick each location in the string and replace it with value defined in `replacement`.

Good thing to note is the fact that if you will use `strSample = strSample.replace(" ","p");` which means one white space character as `target` value then nothing will be replaced because now in this case `replace` method will try to search for a white space character.

Comment: @Mr. downvoter: Any reasons for down vote ?? It is such a poor display of spirit to down vote and run, but doesn't show courage to support your reason.

Comment: @ForguesR Dude, I wish you had some good reason and you had understood the meaning of "down vote". Down vote is not a button to be used when you are answering a question and out of respite you want other answers to be have lesser votes than you. Down vote means that answer is not useful and irrelevant. Now I have used the info from Java docs and explained it so it cannot be wrong. Moreover, more-or-less you are also giving same information along of redundant garbage.

Comment: @ForguesR I am not looking forward for your reversal of vote, its more about your irrational behavior and reason for down vote.

Answer (score 1):

The native Java `java.lang.String` implementation (like Ruby and Python) considers empty string `""` a valid character sequence while performing string operations. Therefore the `""` character sequence is effectively **everywhere** between two chars including before and after the last character.

It works coherently with all `java.lang.String` operations. See :

```
String abc = "abc";
System.out.println(abc.replace("", "a"));  // aaabaca instead of "abc"
System.out.println(abc.indexOf("", "a"));  // 0 instead of -1
System.out.println(abc.contains("", "a")); // true instead of false
```

**As a side note :**

This behavior might be misleading because many other languages / implementations do not behave like this.  For instance, SQL (MySQL, MSSQL, Oracle and PostgreSQL) and PHP do not considers `""` like a valid character sequence for string replacement.  .NET goes further and throws `System.ArgumentException: String cannot be of zero length.` when calling, for instance, `abc.Replace("", "a")`.

Even the popular Apache Commons Lang Java library works differently :

```
org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.replace("abc", "", "a")); /* abc */
```

Comment: You are not directly answering the OP's question but inflating your answer with a lot of redundant and irrelevant information. You are quoting, `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.replace` but its a library and not a language, you can create a library to do whatever you want, now this doesn't mean that language has or has not support for it. Op doesn't want to know what happens in other 1000 languages present in world but wants to understand the behaviour in Java.

Comment: @hagrawal Thanks for your comment, I edited my answer.  OP wants to understand the behavior of `java.lang.String`.  I'd also add than `org.apache.commons.lang` is not an home made String library but a very popular Java library with a replace function that works differently than the native `java.lang.String`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example:

```
"" + "abc" + ""
```

What is result of this code?
Answer: it is still `"abc"`. So as you see we can say that all strings have some empty strings before and after it.

Same rule applies in-between characters like

```
"a"+""+"b"+""+"c"
```

will still create `"abc"`

So empty strings also exists between characters.

In your code

```
"val".replace("","p")
```

all these empty strings ware replaced with `p` which result in `pvpaplp`.

---

In case of `""+""+..+""+""` assume that Java is smart enough to see it as one `""`.

Comment: Then you could argue that `"a"+""+"b" == "a"+""+""+""+""+"b"` so why `p` would not be replaced 4 times in-between? (tricky reasoning he?)

Comment: @Tunaki Damn it. I was trying to avoid this question since presented logic allows to easier remember general idea while not covering all details :)

Comment: Yes I see what you mean :)